# Fails to resume from suspend in 16.10

Tags: suspend, screen, 16.10, resume

About half the time I attempt to resume from suspend, it gets stuck at a black screen. Diagnostically, I've also noticed that while it's suspending, the screen goes black for a second, returns to normal, then goes into suspend.

I have Ubuntu 16.10 with kernel 4.8.0-27-generic. It's a desktop with three monitors.

Here's `lshw -c video`:

```
lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Here's `lshw` (slightly truncated because of SE's length limit):

```
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: System Product Name (To be filled by O.E.M.)
    vendor: System manufacturer
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=To be filled by O.E.M. uuid=20091912-A3D8-DD11-A71A-C86000C0BEF6
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: P8Z68-V GEN3
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev 1.xx
       serial: MT7022045303513
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 3201
          date: 02/15/2012
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: LGA1155
          size: 2527MHz
          capacity: 5900MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=1 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2 DISABLED
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3-Cache
             size: 8MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: internal unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 5b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 0
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1866C10D3/8G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 4D301D6E
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: CML8GX3M2A1600C9
             vendor: AMI
             physical id: 2
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: CML8GX3M2A1600C9
             vendor: AMI
             physical id: 3
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=snb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:46 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:f752c000-f752c00f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 05
             serial: c8:60:00:c0:be:f6
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:42 memory:f7500000-f751ffff memory:f7529000-f7529fff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7528000-f75283ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.8.0-27-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: USB Receiver
                      vendor: Logitech
                      physical id: 5
                      bus info: usb@1:1.5
                      version: 12.01
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:f7520000-f7523fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f2100000-f22fffff ioport:f2300000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 memory:f7400000-f74fffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi msix pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7400000-f7407fff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.8.0-27-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@3
                   logical name: usb3
                   version: 4.08
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: USB hub
                      product: USB2.0 Hub
                      vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@3:1
                      version: 90.80
                      capabilities: usb-2.10
                      configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usb:0
                         description: Keyboard
                         product: USB Receiver
                         vendor: Logitech
                         physical id: 3
                         bus info: usb@3:1.3
                         version: 12.03
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
                    *-usb:1
                         description: Mass storage device
                         product: USB Storage
                         vendor: Generic
                         physical id: 4
                         bus info: usb@3:1.4
                         logical name: scsi8
                         version: 3.10
                         serial: 000000000310
                         capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                         configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                       *-disk
                            description: SCSI Disk
                            product: STORAGE DEVICE
                            vendor: Generic
                            physical id: 0.0.0
                            bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
                            logical name: /dev/sdc
                            version: 0310
                            capabilities: removable
                            configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                          *-medium
                               physical id: 0
                               logical name: /dev/sdc
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.8.0-27-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4
                   logical name: usb4
                   version: 4.08
                   capabilities: usb-3.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: USB hub
                      product: USB3.0 Hub
                      vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@4:1
                      version: 90.84
                      capabilities: usb-3.00
                      configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7300000-f73fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlp4s0
                version: bb
                serial: 7c:5c:f8:4f:fe:8e
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-27-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.0.50 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:44 memory:f7300000-f7301fff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7200000-f72fffff
           *-storage
                description: SATA controller
                product: JMB362 SATA Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                version: 10
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
                resources: irq:19 ioport:d040(size=8) ioport:d030(size=4) ioport:d020(size=8) ioport:d010(size=4) ioport:d000(size=16) memory:f7210000-f72101ff memory:f7200000-f720ffff
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7100000-f71fffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi msix pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f7100000-f7107fff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.8.0-27-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@5
                   logical name: usb5
                   version: 4.08
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.8.0-27-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@6
                   logical name: usb6
                   version: 4.08
                   capabilities: usb-3.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-pci:6
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7527000-f75273ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.8.0-27-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
```